# Setting NS for Subdomain to Another Hosted Zone with Same Apex Domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, dns-servers, route53

Suppose I own `example.com`.

I delegate the subdomain `www.example.com` to a particular set of NS that is say a Route53 Hosted Zone. The rest of the `example.com` zone is not on R53 and contains important information for other subdomain/records. You can consider this Zone 1, and you can consider the new R53 Hosted Zone as Zone 2.

I want to have `www.example.com` CNAMEd to a particular endpoint, say a cloudfront distribution. Since I can't `CNAME` the apex domain, instead hosted zone 2 is created in R53 with the original apex domain: `example.com`. Then, inside that hosted zone, there is a record for the subdomain `www.example.com` with the `CNAME` to `xxx.cloudfront.net`.

I can't directly configure `www.example.com` with the CNAME in hosted zone 1 for various reasons, including that the CNAME is always changing and the person controlling the CNAME only has control over zone 2.

So the full chain looks like this: User types in `www.example.com`, they get NS hosted 1 records. In that zone, the record for `www.example.com` points to Hosted zone 2 records. In this zone (which was created with apex `example.com`) the record for `www.example.com` is a `CNAME` to the proper endpoint.

My question: will any DNS resolvers mistakenly cache the NS from the second zone as apex domain records? Obviously, I want those NS accessed only for the `www.example.com` records. If `example.com` `NS` records are mistakenly thought of as in hosted zone 2, there can be a lot of issues.

If this is the case, is there any way to make sure to DNS resolvers that the apex domain nameservers are zone 1, and zone 2 records are ONLY for `www.example.com`, even though they were created with the `example.com` apex domain?

I understand that there are other ways to do this (`CNAME` to separate domain, etc) but for logistical purposes (for now) I am only interested in setting the `NS` directly for the `www` subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

While unusual, you can certainly delegate `www.example.com` to a different set of nameservers than `example.com`.

There is no reason for nameservers to cache nameservers authoritative on `www.example.com` as authoritative for `example.com`, so this problem will never happen.

But by delegating `www` you close the option for example to have it as a `CNAME`, and I am just mentioning it for completion, as it seems exactly what you want to fly away.

To say differently: if your `example.com` zone has `NS` records for `www.example.com` to delegate it further to a second set of nameserver, you CAN NOT have at the same time a `CNAME` record on `www` in the `example.com` zone. This setup won't be accepted by any decent nameservers, the authoritative ones on `example.com` would/should refuse to load such a zone.

The authoritative nameservers for `www.example.com` must be authoritative for `www.example.com` this is their apex, not `example.com`.  They can not be configured to be authoritative for `example.com`, nor can they have a `CNAME` record for `www` as `www.example.com` since this is their apex and hence already has `SOA` and `NS` records which makes `CNAME` presence impossible. That part is not very clear from your question, so not sure to follow (things are far clearer with real names and dig outputs...)

Note that of course the nameservers for `www.example.com` must be "real" nameservers replying correctly on the DNS level for many things, and not just `A` query types, like `SOA` and `NS` record types.
I am writing that because, from experience, when I saw people delegating `www` it was often to close boxes acting as load balancer and handling both HTTP(S) and DNS traffic, unfortunately they were often very broken at the DNS level (not reply to `NS` queries for example or answering `NS` queries with `A` records pointing back to themselves or other nightmares...) which created all sort of difficult edge cases. So just saying so in passing, make sure to delegate your `www` to something that really acts as a nameserver and not just pretend to be one on the surface.

Also, you may not want to hear that, but still, since your premise is "the CNAME is always changing and the person controlling the CNAME only has control over zone 2." and then you try to work around this, the real proper solution is instead:

`www.example.com CNAME www.example.com.your-provider.example`

and then your provider is free to fiddle with the record `www.example.com.your-provider.example` as much as it wants and even make it a CNAME changing each 5 minutes. It has full control over it, and you gave him the authority over it thanks to your own `CNAME` that will stay once for all, without you having to really delegate, at the DNS level, part of your zone to other nameservers.

I am not claiming this is the same case, but observe the similarity:

```
$ dig www.microsoft.com +noall +ans
www.microsoft.com.  8m51s IN CNAME www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.
www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net. 7m25s IN CNAME www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net. 8m24s IN CNAME e13678.dspb.akamaiedge.net.
e13678.dspb.akamaiedge.net. 14s IN A 23.217.196.148
```

Comment: I think you might be slightly misunderstanding. www.example.com is pointing to the Zone 2 with those nameservers, but the zone is created with example.com as an apex domain (example.com NS xx.awsns060.org). Then there is a record for www.example.com which is a CNAME to an endpoint. Essentially, there are now 2 zones (zone 1 and zone 2) both with the same apex. The difference is that the original zone has the www record pointing to the other zone. I see that this is digging fine when I implement it- I am just worried that some resolver somewhere will think that zone 2 is authority for the apex

Comment: "www.example.com is pointing to the Zone 2 with those nameservers, but the zone is created with example.com as an apex domain (example.com NS xx.awsns060.org" this is not how the DNS works, and you will only create problems for yourself (which you can easily avoid just if you accept to stop trying to go around the real problem). Besides, "I think you might be slightly misunderstanding", probably, but if you used real names and real examples I am sure it would be easier for everyone. Obfuscation, specially for the DNS which is public, is not needed.Let us see if others can understand it better.

Comment: You said that this can cause problems- if you can elaborate on the nature, that would be helpful. Thanks!